# Alternative to INTERSECT Given Arbitrary Number of conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a table similar to the following:

```
MyIds MyValues
----- --------
  1    Meat
  1    Fruit
  1    Veggies
  2    Fruit
  2    Meat
  3    Meat
```

How do I create a query  such that if I am given an arbitrary list of distinct `MyValues`, it will give me all the `MyIds` that match **all** of `MyValues`.

Example: If list of `MyValues` contained [Meat, Fruit, Veggies], I'd like to get `MyIds` of `1` back because `1` has an entry in the table for each value in MyValues.

I know that this can be done with an INTERSECT if I'm given a specific list of `MyValues`. But I don't know how it can be done with an arbitrary number of `MyValues`

Comment: [Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to count the total number of instances of each `MyID` which satisfies the condition and that it matches to the number of value supplied in the `IN` clause.

```
SELECT MyID
FROM tableName
WHERE MyValues IN ('Meat', 'Fruit', 'Veggies')
GROUP BY MyID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT myVAlues) = 3
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/860dd/2)

Answer (score 0):

A big question is how the list is being represented.  The following gives one approach, representing the list in a table:

```
with l as ( 
    select 'Meat' as el union all
    select 'Fruit' union all
    select 'Veggies'
)
select MyId
from t join
     l
     on t.MyValues = l.el
group by MyId
having count(distinct t.myvalues) = (select count(*) from l)
```